# Unique Random Numbers using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a series of unique (non-duplicating) random numbers within a user defined range.  I have managed to create the random numbers, but I am getting duplicate values.  How can I ensure that the random numbers will never be a duplicate?

```
Sub GenerateCodesUser()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Users").Activate

    Dim MINNUMBER As Long
    Dim MAXNUMBER As Long

    MINNUMBER = 1000
    MAXNUMBER = 9999999

    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Number As Long
    Dim high As Double
    Dim Low As Double
    Dim i As Integer

    If (CustomCodes.CardNumberMin.Value = "") Then
        MsgBox ("Fill Card Number Field!")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (CustomCodes.CardNumberMin.Value < MINNUMBER) Then
        MsgBox ("Card Number Value must be equal or higher then" & MINNUMBER)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If (CustomCodes.CardNumberMax.Value = "") Then
        MsgBox ("Fill Card Number Field!")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (CustomCodes.CardNumberMax.Value > MAXNUMBER) Then
        MsgBox ("Card Number Value must be equal or higher then " & MAXNUMBER)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Low = CustomCodes.CardNumberMin.Value
    high = CustomCodes.CardNumberMax.Value '<<< CHANGE AS DESIRED

    If (Low < 1000) Then
        'break
    End If

    For i = 1 To Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        If InStr(Cells(1, i), "CardNumber") Then
            Row = 2
            While Cells(Row, 1) <> 0
                Do
                    Number = ((high - Low + 1) * Rnd() + Low)
                Loop Until Number > Low
                Cells(Row, i) = Number
                Row = Row + 1
            Wend
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you're doing no checks for duplicates, it's not surprising you get some...  Is it important that numbers be random?  Why not just fill the numbers in sequence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a method of guaranteeing unique *integer* random numbers.  Inline comments describe the method.

```vb
Function UniuqeRandom(Mn As Long, Mx As Long, Sample As Long) As Long()
    Dim dat() As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim tmp As Long

    ' Input validation checks here
    If Mn > Mx Or Sample > (Mx - Mn + 1) Then
        ' declare error to suit your needs
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' size array to hold all possible values
    ReDim dat(0 To Mx - Mn)

    ' Fill the array
    For i = 0 To UBound(dat)
        dat(i) = Mn + i
    Next

    ' Shuffle array, unbiased
    For i = UBound(dat) To 1 Step -1
        tmp = dat(i)
        j = Int((i + 1) * Rnd)
        dat(i) = dat(j)
        dat(j) = tmp
    Next

    'original biased shuffle
    'For i = 0 To UBound(dat)
    '    tmp = dat(i)
    '    j = Int((Mx - Mn) * Rnd)
    '    dat(i) = dat(j)
    '    dat(j) = tmp
    'Next

    ' Return sample
    ReDim Preserve dat(0 To Sample - 1)
    UniuqeRandom = dat
End Function
```

use it like this

```
Dim low As Long, high As Long

Dim rng As Range
Dim dat() As Long

Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight))
dat = UniuqeRandom(low, high, rng.Columns.Count)
rng.Offset(1, 0) = dat
```

Note: see [this Wikipedia article regarding shuffle bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

The edit fixed one source of bias.  The inherent limitations of `Rnd` (based on a 32 bit seed) and Modulo bias remain.

Comment: Hi Chris,thank you verymuch for your help, I'll gonna insert this into my code and test, I'll came shortly with news

Comment: This shuffle looks [biased](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Potential_sources_of_bias). Should that matter to you, you can implement Knuth's shuffle or sort by random keys.

Comment: Hi Guy's.thank you very much for your help, it was very much appreciate.                                                            Regarding the issue I've "solved" with this code, it works for me and cover's all my needs.                                                              Tank you very much for your help                                                                    Best regards                                                               carlos

Answer (score 1):

I see you have an accepted answer, but for whatever it's worth here is my stab at this question. This one uses a boolean function instead of numerical arrays. It's very simple yet fast. The advantage of it, which I'm not saying is perfect, is an effective solution for numbers in a long range because you only ever check the numbers you have already picked and saved and don't need a potentially large array to hold the values you have rejected so it won't cause memory problems because of the size of the array.

```
Sub UniqueRandomGenerator()
Dim N As Long, MaxNum As Long, MinNum As Long, Rand As Long, i As Long

MinNum = 1        'Put the input of minimum number here
MaxNum = 100      'Put the input of maximum number here
N = MaxNum - MinNum + 1

ReDim Unique(1 To N, 1 To 1)

For i = 1 To N
Randomize         'I put this inside the loop to make sure of generating "good" random numbers
    Do
        Rand = Int(MinNum + N * Rnd)
        If IsUnique(Rand, Unique) Then Unique(i, 1) = Rand:  Exit Do
    Loop
Next
Sheet1.[A1].Resize(N) = Unique
End Sub

Function IsUnique(Num As Long, Data As Variant) As Boolean
Dim iFind As Long

On Error GoTo Unique
iFind = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Num, Data, 0)

If iFind > 0 Then IsUnique = False: Exit Function

Unique:
    IsUnique = True
End Function
```

Comment: How does this code work? I tried running it, nothing happens.

Comment: @Max Have you checked the output in Sheet1 column A?

Comment: Yes, I did. Just empty cells. It doesn't give any results. I use excel 2010.

Comment: @Max It's perfectly work in Excel 2010 & 2013. I've tried it on both platforms. Not sure what's wrong with yours

Comment: Is it possible that you can share a link to a sample excel file ? please

Comment: @Max Sure. Find the file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-epzYWtJ2i1YGtbQxItHNkYz8EC00J1e)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Anastasiya. It works. I don't know why I couldn't do it in the first place.

Comment: Pretty awesome...  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It Works perfectly:

```
Option Base 1
Public Function u(a As Variant, b As Variant) As Variant
 Application.Volatile
 Dim k%, p As Double, flag As Boolean, x() As Variant
    k = 1
  flag = False
  ReDim x(1)
   x(1) = Application.RandBetween(a, b)
  Do Until k = b - a + 1

   Do While flag = False
   Randomize
    p = Application.RandBetween(a, b)
     'Debug.Assert p = 2
    resultado = Application.Match(p, x, False)
     If IsError(resultado) Then
      k = k + 1
      ReDim Preserve x(k)
      x(k) = p
       flag = True
      Else
       flag = False
      End If
   Loop
   flag = False
  Loop
  u = x
End Function
```