# How do I create an array with random numbers?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, random

I'm new at this. I want to create an array of 16 elements. Let's say that my array is ReDim arr(15) as Integer and in that array I want to put the numbers from 1 to 16 but scrambled, for example arr(0) = 3, arr(5) = 8 and so on.

Comment: `arr(15)` only gives you 15 elements.

Comment: So...have you tried anything

Comment: `arr(15)` (aka `arr(0 to 15)`) gives 16 elements.

Comment: I thought the number gives you number of elements so arr(15) would be 0-14? But Jeeped is always right ^_^; Edit: ah, the number is upperbound not elements. But if you have option base of 1, then it's elements =P Edit2: so I have been doing it all wrong XD

Comment: Yeah, if just a single value is in the brackets, it treats it as the upper bound, with 0 as the lower bound.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543169/unique-random-numbers-using-vba)?

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
Sub MAIN()
   Dim ary(1 To 16) As Variant
   Dim i As Long, msg As String

   For i = 1 To 16
      ary(i) = i
   Next i

   Call Shuffle(ary)

   msg = ""
   For i = 1 To 16
      msg = msg & vbCrLf & ary(i)
   Next i
   MsgBox msg
End Sub

Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim HowMany As Long, i As Long, J As Long
    Dim tempF As Double, temp As Variant

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For i = Low To Hi
        Helper(i) = Rnd
    Next i


    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - J
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = tempF
            temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = tempF
            temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = temp
          End If
        Next i
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is some very lazy code:

```
Dim arr(15) As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
i = 1
Do
    j = Int(16 * Rnd)
    If arr(j) = 0 Then
        arr(j) = i
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop Until i = 17
```

Rnd generates a `single` from 0 to 1, multiply that by 16 and strip the decimal portion with `Int` and it will give you a random number from 0 to 15.

It isn't efficient, I wouldn't use this in production, but it'll do the job.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No it wont, I thought of that in this code. If the rnd function returns a value that has already been used, it will just restart the loop.

Comment: You are correct, I apologize and will delete my comment.  I missed the if statement.  This works great for the requested small subset.  I would be interested in knowing the average number loops to get them all filled.  By the odds there is a chance of an infinite loop if the subset got to large.  That is not what was asked, and this small of a subset would not run that risk.

Comment: Yeah, as I said it isn't great code but it'll do the job here of you are only going to use it for small sets. I ran it 500 times and it took an average of 35 loops to complete, but all 500 took less than a second, so I'm not too worried. If this was code for a serious production I would write it properly.