# Filling an array with random numbers using GoTo in visual basic

Tags: vba, random, goto

Here is some code that I have. I need to know if the technique I am using will fill the array named 'usednum' with truly random numbers or if the numbers are going to be repeated often in the same place. Also, is there a better randomizer I can use that is more 'random'. (PS. I am aware that GoTo is inefficient/hated but that is at the least of my concerns at the moment)

```
Sub Randomizer()
    For x = 0 To 9
Start:
        randomint = (Rnd() * 9) + 1

        If randomint = usednum(0) Then
            GoTo Start
        ElseIf randomint = usednum(1) Then
            GoTo Start
        ElseIf randomint = usednum(2) Then
            GoTo Start
        ElseIf randomint = usednum(3) Then
            GoTo Start
        ElseIf randomint = usednum(4) Then
            GoTo Start
        ElseIf randomint = usednum(5) Then
            GoTo Start
        ElseIf randomint = usednum(6) Then
            GoTo Start
        ElseIf randomint = usednum(7) Then
            GoTo Start
        ElseIf randomint = usednum(8) Then
            GoTo Start
        Else
            usednum(x) = randomint
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tested the code yourself?  What have you observed?

Comment: @roryap I have observed that usednum(9) is often the same number

Comment: That is because you do not check it.  You need to make one more `elseif` statement.

Comment: Check out the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534263/how-do-i-create-an-array-with-random-numbers) for better methods to do this.

Comment: @Scott Craner I added one for usednum(9) but no progress. usednum(9) for some reason either likes to be 1 or 10

Comment: @Scott Craner might just change my randomizer completely because by the looks of it, it isn't too efficient

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted, particularly @AndrewWynn answer, Just change the numbers and you will get what you want.

Comment: @Scott Craner Just looked at the link and changed my code accordingly, and it looks like it works now. Thanks a lot for your help :)