# Checking a random Value against an Array to prevent duplicates

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, while-loop

I am presently trying to write a script that would pull a random meal from a list of meals and input them in a calendar. It generates 4 weeks (Sunday through Saturday), with two different meals per week. I would like to have it check each time it pulls a random meal from the list against the meals that it has already pulled to prevent the same meal from coming up twice in one month. Following is what I have written:

```
Dim ranDnr As Integer
Dim ranDnr2 As Integer
Dim usdMls(3) As Integer
Dim usdMls2(3) As Integer

Sub GnrtMlsMnthClndr()
Randomize

For i = 0 To 3
For j = 0 To 3
For x = 2 To 17 Step 5
For y = 2 To 17 Step 5

    ranDnr = Int(60 * Rnd + 1)

    While IsInArray(ByVal ranDnr, ByVal usdMls) = True
        ranDnr = Int(60 * Rnd + 1)
    Wend
    usdMls(i) = ranDnr
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ranDnr, 1)

    ranDnr2 = Int(60 * Rnd + 1)

    While IsInArray2(ByVal ranDnr2, ByVal usdMls2) = True
        ranDnr2 = Int(60 * Rnd + 1)
    Wend
    usdMls2(j) = ranDnr2
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 9) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ranDnr2, 1)

Next y
Next x
Next j
Next i

End Sub

Public Function IsInArray(ByVal ranDnr, ByVal usdMls) As Boolean
    'Dim i
    For i = 0 To 3
        If usdMls(i) = ranDnr Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False

End Function

Public Function IsInArray2(ByVal ranDnr2, ByVal usdMls2) As Boolean
    'Dim i
    For i = 0 To 3
        If usdMls2(i) = ranDnr2 Then
            IsInArray2 = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray2 = False

End Function
```

I am really inexperienced in VBA and have absolutely no idea why this doesn't work, as it seems logical to me and doesn't generate any errors when I run it. Any assistance that could be provided would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create an array with random numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534263/how-do-i-create-an-array-with-random-numbers)

Comment: Please indent your code properly and did you really mean to have those Dim statements at the top outside of your Sub?