# Unique random number generator VBA code issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a lottery generator of 5 box, idea is each box will have **unique** number every time I randomize it,

My code

```
If TextBox1.Value = TextBox2.Value Or TextBox1.Value = TextBox3.Value Or TextBox1.Value = TextBox4.Value Or TextBox1.Value = TextBox5.Value Then
    TextBox1.Value = TextBox1.Value + 1
ElseIf TextBox2.Value = TextBox1.Value Or TextBox2.Value = TextBox3.Value Or TextBox2.Value = TextBox4.Value Or TextBox2.Value = TextBox5.Value Then
    TextBox2.Value = TextBox2.Value + 1
ElseIf TextBox3.Value = TextBox1.Value Or TextBox3.Value = TextBox2.Value Or TextBox3.Value = TextBox4.Value Or TextBox3.Value = TextBox5.Value Then
    TextBox3.Value = TextBox3.Value + 1
ElseIf TextBox4.Value = TextBox1.Value Or TextBox4.Value = TextBox2.Value Or TextBox4.Value = TextBox3.Value Or TextBox4.Value = TextBox5.Value Then
    TextBox4.Value = TextBox4.Value + 1
ElseIf TextBox5.Value = TextBox1.Value Or TextBox5.Value = TextBox2.Value Or TextBox5.Value = TextBox3.Value Or TextBox5.Value = TextBox4.Value Then
    TextBox5.Value = TextBox5.Value + 1
End If
```

Kindly focus on the highlighted code, this is my code to make unique random number in each 5 boxes, but, sometimes 1 in 100 it gives me the same number for any two box

Comment: Use a [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18543169/445425) (get a list of all possible values, shuffle it, then take 5 off the top)

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Office 365](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_365) and you want each textbox to have a random value from 1 to 100 with no repeats, then generate an array with:

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
        arr = .SortBy(.Sequence(100), .RandArray(100), 1)
End With
```

And then:

```
TextBox1.Value = arr(1,1)
TextBox2.Value = arr(2,1)
TextBox3.Value = arr(3,1)
TextBox4.Value = arr(4,1)
TextBox5.Value = arr(5,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a formula on the sheet, itself...

A1..A*n* =RAND(), B1..B*n* =1..*n*

[image: Random numbers]

Then sort on the A column - top five numbers will float to the top.

[image: Numbers after sort]

The beauty of this method is that every time you sort, the numbers are changed (pseudo) randomly again.  *(And no VBA necessary!)*